# Textbox focus does not work

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using VS2015 and currently I am under pressure of this issue and I don't know why it's not working on VS2015.

I do have a "Splash Screen" which is a welcome page and after that will be another page to show some other forms. I do have 5 borders represent as a container, each border will show after hit next and all of the borders are place only in the same View which is `MainWindow.xaml`.

Every field just like `Name` textbox field do have a `Validation.ErrorTemplate`and I am not sure if that will affect the textbox focus.

I used `FocusManager.FocusedElement` and `text1.focus()` but still not working and other solution coming from other people having similar issues but still not working in my end.

I am guessing something in logical focus but when I force to focus the textbox still not working.

Simple example of XAML.

```
<Border x:Name="Panel1" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="False"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Border.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform />
            <SkewTransform />
            <RotateTransform />
            <TranslateTransform Y="515" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Border.RenderTransform>
    <Grid Background="{DynamicResource ActiveBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,10,0,76.33" Height="450" Width="630" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      Template="{DynamicResource ContentPanelScrollviewerStyle}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="630">
                <Label Content="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       FontSize="{DynamicResource FieldGroupHeadingTextSize}"
                       Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
                <Grid Height="170">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Column="0" IsVisibleChanged="Grid_IsVisibleChanged">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Label Content="Name"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   FontSize="{DynamicResource FieldLabelTextSize}"
                                   Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
                            <TextBox Name="text1" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                     Text="{Binding Name, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="298.8" Height="24"
                                     FontSize="{DynamicResource FieldInputTextSize}"
                                     Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBrush}">
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <behaviors:ReadOnlyWhileValidatingBehavior />
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </TextBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Please show us some XAML that reproduces the issue you're having.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I posted a simple example of my XAML. Thanks

Comment: You say *"I used FocusManager.FocusedElement and text1.focus()"* -- please show where so I can reproduce the exact way your code is working.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I removed it since it's not working, so what happen is that I added FocusManager.FocusedElement on my textbox like this "_FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"_" and text1.Focus() calls onload.

Comment: @EdPlunkett is this possible because of this _<behaviors:ReadOnlyWhileValidatingBehavior />_?